# How is LTE organized in NB-IoT

Tags: smart-home, security

How is LTE organized in NB-IoT? And can one find vulnerabilities in NB-IoT technology (security)?

Comment: Welcome! "How to find vulnerabilities" is a very broad question, and hard to answer without more details. Take a look at our tips on [ask] and consider making an [edit] to make your question more specific, and make sure you only ask one question in your post.

Comment: Plus, there is also https://security.stackexchange.com/  But I am not sure that "please help me hack" questions are welcome on any S.E site

Answer (score 3):

Let's start by dissecting the question.

**How is LTE organized in NB-IoT?**

According to Wikipedia:

> NarrowBand IoT (NB-IoT) is a Low Power Wide Area Network (LPWAN) radio technology standard developed to enable a wide range of devices and services such as in Internet of Things (IoT) to be connected using cellular telecommunications bands standardized by the 3rd Generation Partnership Project (3GPP).
>
> NB-IoT focuses specifically on indoor coverage, low cost, long battery life, and enabling a large number of connected devices. The NB-IoT technology is deployed “in-band” in spectrum allocated to Long Term Evolution (LTE) - using resource blocks within a normal LTE carrier, or in the unused resource blocks within a LTE carrier’s guard-band - or “standalone” for deployments in dedicated spectrum.

According to an [Electronic Design](http://www.electronicdesign.com/blog/getting-acquainted-nb-iot) blog:

> NB-IoT uses less bandwidth than any other version of LTE—specifically, 200 kHz vs. the smallest previously defined LTE bandwidth of 1.4 MHz. In fact the NB-IoT signal is exactly one LTE Physical Resource Block (PRB) wide. A PRB is the basic building block of LTE’s OFDM signals. This means 12 subcarriers that are 15 kHz wide, making a total of 180 kHz.

**How to find security vulnerabilities in NB-IoT?**

> IoT devices is expected to grow by 21 percent annually, rising to 18 billion between now and 2022 and this will create a need to manage large numbers of different types of devices. The sheer number and diversity of these IoT devices will increase room for vulnerabilities. To find vulnerability on NB-IoT, you will probe for security gaps on an established security policy framework. Say, for instance, the system can scanned for abnormal traffic, scan for open telnet service running to detect DDoS attacks since some IoTs still uses telnet

(As proposed by an [Ericsson whitepaper](https://www.ericsson.com/assets/local/publications/white-papers/wp-iot-security-february-2017.pdf).)

To simply state, the security of NB-IoT is for the devices to be configured, managed and monitored securely. Going by a white paper by [Transatel](http://www.transatel.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Security-for-the-IoT_Feb_2017_high-res-1.pdf), *"Security for The IoT"*, if you already have the security features in place, you may find vulnerabilities by:

- Probing for NB-IoT Devices Identity: *"Devices can be authenticated when they communicate with other things, services, or users. Strong identity allows us to address core security requirements, such as trust, privacy, and integrity"*
- Probing for NB-IoT Devices Public Key Infrastructure (PKI): *"This is an already established and standard security technology that can be incorporated to protect the system. In a PKI, asymmetric cryptography, using private keys in combination with certificates, allows devices to identify themselves over NB-IoT."*